# keep the solution in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

i am trying to get the frequency of terms within a collection of variable length strings.The context is descriptions in an Access database. Would prefer to keep the solution in VBA. Delimiter is " " (space) character

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

Call wordfreq

End Sub

Function wordfreq()

    Dim myCol As Collection
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim strArray As Variant
    Dim strDescr, strTerm, strMsg As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    Set myCol = New Collection

    strDescr = "here it should accept the table and display the result in seperate table"
'    db.Execute "select columns from table"

    myArray = Split(strDescr, " ")

    For Each strArray In myArray
        On Error Resume Next
        myCol.Add strArray, CStr(strArray)
    Next strArray

    For i = 1 To myCol.Count
        strTerm = myCol(i)
        j = 0
        For Each strArray In myArray
            If strArray = strTerm Then j = j + 1
        Next strArray
        'placeholder
        strMsg = strMsg & strTerm & " --->" & j & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
    Next i

    'placeholder
    'save results into a table
    MsgBox strMsg

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Using a dictionary object for frequency counts is much more natural than using a collection. See this: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html

Comment: can you help with the code here as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See an example below using a `Scripting.Dictionary` object.

```
Function wordfreq()

    Dim objDict As Object
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim idx As Long

    Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    strInput = "here it should accept the table and display the result in seperate table"
    myArray = Split(strInput, " ")

    For idx = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If Not objDict.Exists(myArray(idx)) Then
            'Add to dictionary with a count of 1
            objDict(myArray(idx)) = 1
        Else
            'Increment counter
            objDict(myArray(idx)) = objDict(myArray(idx)) + 1
        End If

    Next

    'Test it
    Dim n As Variant
    For Each n In objDict.Keys
        Debug.Print "Word: " & n, " Count: " & objDict(n)
    Next
End Function
```

Output:

```
'Word: here                  Count: 1
'Word: it                    Count: 1
'Word: should                Count: 1
'Word: accept                Count: 1
'Word: the                   Count: 2
'Word: table                 Count: 2
'Word: and                   Count: 1
'Word: display               Count: 1
'Word: result                Count: 1
'Word: in                    Count: 1
'Word: seperate              Count: 1
```

### Edit

The process:

1. Loop through the **Input** `recordset`.
2. Split the **Description** into words.
3. Check if the word exist in `Dictionary` and **add** or
   **increment**.
4. Add the `Keys` (words) and `Values` (count) of the aforementioned
   `Dictionary` to the **Output** table.

To achieve this two helper functions have been set up:

1. One loops through the description `recordset` and returns a
   `Dictionary` object filled with unique words as `Keys` and their
   count as `Values`.
2. The other takes the above `Dictionary`object and adds it to the Output table.

You need to change `[TABLE]` to the name of your Input and Output tables.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub WordsFrequency()
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT Description FROM [TABLE] WHERE Description Is Not Null;", dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave
    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    If AddDictionaryToTable(ToDictionary(rs)) Then
        MsgBox "Completed successfully.", vbInformation
    End If

Leave:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

---

```
' Returns Scripting.Dictionary object
Private Function ToDictionary(rs As DAO.Recordset) As Object

    Dim d As Object             'Dictionary
    Dim v As Variant            'Words
    Dim w As String             'Word
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long   'Loops

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        v = Split(rs![Description], " ")

        For ii = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            w = Trim(v(ii))
            If Not d.Exists(w) Then d(w) = 1 Else d(w) = d(w) + 1
        Next

        rs.MoveNext
    Next

    Set ToDictionary = d
End Function
```

---

```
' Adds Dictionary object to table
Private Function AddDictionaryToTable(objDict As Object) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim n As Variant

    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("[TABLE]")
    With rs
        For Each n In objDict.Keys
            .AddNew
            .Fields("Words").Value = n
            .Fields("Counts").Value = objDict(n)
            .Update
        Next
    End With

    'all good
    AddDictionaryToTable = True

Leave:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

Comment: Dude, do you really expect me to write the whole program for you? Show some effort and try to adapt the above example into your program. If you get stuck, then ask.

Comment: i am weak in vba

Comment: i have added the screenshot to the above question, it has table Name fields and columns. please check and advise